# can I use mpld3 in a loop to create multiple plots?

Tags: python, mpld3

I tried to create multiple mpld3 figures with a loop. However, nothing is produced:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpld3
mpld3.enable_notebook()
for i in range(0, 10):
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([1,3], [2,4], 'bo')
    mpld3.display(fig)
```

However, I can create figure if I use this code:

```
i=0
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,3], [2,4], 'bo')
mpld3.display(fig)
```

Also, I found that I wont get anything if the mpld3.display() is called in a if clause like this

```
if True: 
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([1,3], [2,4], 'bo')
    mpld3.display(fig)
```

But I can get the plot if I use

```
if True: 
    fig,ax=plt.subplots()
    ax.plot([1,3], [2,4], 'bo')
mpld3.display(fig)
```

Anyone knows why?  I am using jupyter notebook.

Comment: Any update so far? The same issue.